# Email Validation using HTML5

Tags: html, validation, email

I need to create an email validation code which has live validation and has a success message box at the end.

For the purposes of this task an email address must:

• Start with a string of alphanumeric characters

• followed by the @ symbol

• another string of alphanumeric characters

• followed by a “ . ”

• then a string of alphanumeric characters.

Eg a@b.c and ab23@f45.d3 are both valid

but @bc.d and 123.c@cvb are not valid

if any of these variables are not met the live validation must say so!

this needs to be in HTML5 and need help FAST!!!!

Comment: `<input type="email"/>`? BTW _123.c@cvb_ is valid per RFC 1123 as cvb could be a top-level domain

Comment: @Rhumborl It's not reliable, but there're many validation libraries out there...

Comment: Note that `type="email"` will give `123.c@cvb` as valid...
You will have to use `regex` i.e JavaScript, to check the email....

Answer (score 0):

You can use a javascript regex to check the email address:

```
var mail = 'john.doe@example.com'
var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  if (!re.test(mail)) {
    window.alert('Invalid email address');
}
```

More info here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_test.asp

Answer (score 0):

A bit hard to know what your actual questions is but as @matías-fidemraizer says in the comments, there are plenty of JavaScript libraries out there that can do this kind of validation and a rather quick web search should give you some good starting points.

If you want some more direct suggestions and as you mention showing a success message etc. Maybe look at  for example the framework [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) and some of the email validation plugins avilable. A quick search gave these two: [Bootstrap Validator](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/) and [BootstrapValidator](http://bootstrapvalidator.com/validators/emailAddress/).

Comment: yes i am aware of the regex's but i need the full code, html% and JavaScipt can anyone help?